# Why does pdb give NameError for variables referenced in "if" clause of list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, list-comprehension

Why does this `NameError` happen?

*(Blank lines before prompts inserted for readability.)*

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.10 (default, Oct  4 2019, 19:39:58)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-23)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import pdb

>>> def blah():
...     foo = "ab"
...     pdb.set_trace()
... 

>>> blah()
--Return--
> <stdin>(3)blah()->None

(Pdb) [bar for bar in "ac" if bar in foo]
*** NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

All of the following work okay:

```
(Pdb) foo
'ab'

(Pdb) [bar for bar in foo]
['a', 'b']

(Pdb) [bar for bar in "ac" if bar in "ab"]
['a']
```

So it is specifically an issue for variables which are referenced in the `if` clause, *other* than the loop variable itself.

Same behaviour as above also seen in `python 3.6.9 (default, Apr 18 2020, 01:56:04)`.

But in python 2 (2.6.6 or 2.7.17), using the same commands as above, I get:

```
(Pdb) [bar for bar in "ac" if bar in foo]
['a']
```

Comment: That's interesting. So in your debug session you can refer to the local variable `foo`, but when it's used in the `if`-clause of your list comprehension it errors. I tried in Python 3.8.3 and observed the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[List comprehensions in Python3 are evaluated with a separate scope, similar to functions.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries) Only the first iterable (`for ... in iterable`) is injected from the outside, all other names are bound as globals or closures. [However, closures are resolved at compile time – they only work when lexically defined in the outer scope containing a name.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names)

Compare this with defining an "inner" function, which shows the same behaviour:

```
-> pdb.set_trace()
(Pdb) foo
'ab'
(Pdb) def bar(): return foo
(Pdb) bar()
*** NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

In the PDB session, the *execution scope* is inside `blah`, but the *lexical scope* is outside. This is similar to defining an "inner" function/comprehension inside or outside its parent function:

```
# lexically scoped `foo` as closure
def blah():
    foo = 3
    def bar():  # !!! Define new scope inside blah
        print(foo)
    bar()  # execute bar inside blah

# `foo` not in scope
def bar():  # !!! Define new scope outside blah
    print(foo)

def blah():
    foo = 3
    bar()  # execute bar inside blah
```

---

> #### [6.2.4. Displays for lists, sets and dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries)
>
> [...]
>
> However, *aside from the iterable expression in the leftmost for
> clause, the comprehension is executed in a separate implicitly nested
> scope.* This ensures that names assigned to in the target list don’t
> “leak” into the enclosing scope.
>
> #### [4.2.2. Resolution of names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names)
>
> [...]
>
> *When a name is used in a code block, it is resolved using the nearest
> enclosing scope.* The set of all such scopes visible to a code block is
> called the block’s environment.